# How can I combine these two executable files?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I had a project P1. I added a wpf project that I'd made in blend4. When I create a setup with installshield, it preduces two .exe files. is it possible to reduce it to one exe file?

P1 exe file only does decide which windows in the P2 should be shown first. and has a blank form which I dont want to show up.

1. Can I create a dll file, set it a start up object,reference to P2 and delete P1?
2. Should I just write P1's classes in P2 and delete P1?

Comment: It's not clear to me why P1 exists at all. Why don't you do the logic that determines the start up window in P2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning on **using that DLL in other projects** go with option **1** 
otherwise I suggest that you use option **2**

Answer (score 0):

It was intentional to create two files. One was for each project.

Considering that P2 is an installer for P1, you would just redistribute P2. People can then install P1 without requiring the executable P1.